# how to run "react-native run-android" against android emulator on custom port? (not 8081)

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

Given that I am already running the react-native packager on a custom port (e.g. 8080, not 8081), how does one then run up the react-native application against an Android Emulator (Windows) on this customer port.

That is when running "react-native run-android" how to make this happen on port 8080?

Background: Can't get android emulator (not device) working for a test react-native project on Windows 7. I'm doing basically:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
'run up emulator from Android Studio'
react-native start --port 8080 [in first CMD window]
react-native run-android [in second CMD window]
=> Then on the emulator I can see its still pointing to 8081 (not 8088).
```

Getting hints that it perhaps should be fixed (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12095) however I'm still not sure how to get a simple app running on the Android simulator (can't use 8081 it's already in use).  Trying to use "adb forward" don't work for an emulator (vs device)

Comment: PS. "react-native run-android --port 8088" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer was to on the emulator, which did have an initial view loaded do:

> Control-M (to open dev menu) > Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device > IP:Port

[took me a while to discover the Control-M being the way to get to the menu]